# Stack pointer/Program counter error MIPs

Tags: stack, runtime-error, mips

This is a function for a part of a program that lets you play Bulls and Cows. 
main jumps and links to the 'guess' label and goes on to get the correct input value.
Now, the function itself runs correctly, but I'm having trouble getting it to go back to main when it's done. 
I'm pretty sure I've set the stack pointer correctly for the correct return address to main be loaded into the $ra when it's time, but it's still giving me a program counter error, and testing has shown me that the counter error indeed happens when it tries to jump back to main.

Since the function call itself utilizes the stack, I checked to make sure I had the $ra loaded from the right space in $sp (in this case, 0($sp) should hold the main's $ra), and it seems to be correct, but the program counter error still prevails at run time.

I would appreciate any input on this matter!

```
    #Gets user's guess and checks

.data
prompt:         .asciiz "\nEnter four unique hexadecimal digits: "
invalidInput:   .asciiz "\nInvalid guess: must be four unique hexadecimal digits"
validInput: .byte       '0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F','a','b','c','d','e','f'
input:  .word   4

.text

#Get the user input
guess:
addi $sp, $sp, -4  #Here is where I save the return address to main
sw $ra, 0($sp)     #

la $a0, prompt  
li $v0, 4       
syscall         

la $a0, input   
li $a1, 5       
li $v0, 8       
syscall         

jal checkAll      #Jumps to the only other call that affects the $sp

#This is the instruction that is flooping around with my program counter, although it seems right! 
lw  $ra, 0($sp)    #When the function is done, load the return address to main
addi    $sp, $sp, 4 
jr  $ra            #jump back to main

#Call to quit - for testing
li $v0, 10
syscall         

#Makes room and gets input validated
checkAll:
addi $sp, $sp, -8     #This function alters the $sp for it's own calls
sw $ra, 8($sp)
sw $a0, 4($sp)

li $s0, 3   
la $a1, validInput
b isValid

lw $a0, 4($sp)      #But then it restores the $sp and is able to link back to the 'guess' call
lw $ra, 8($sp)
addi $sp, $sp, 8
jr $ra  

#Checks each character from the input agaisnt the valid input characters, basically if     the input is hexadecimal 
isValid:
blt $s0, $0, unique

la $t0, ($a0)
add $t1, $s0, $0
add $t2, $t1, $t0
lb $t3, ($t2)   
li $s1, 21  

#Checks each input character agaisnt each valid input character     
checkNum:
blt $s1, $0, invalid            
la $t0, ($a1)
add $t1, $s1, $0
add $t2, $t1, $t0
lb $t4, ($t2) 
bne $t3, $t4, notEqual
j equal

#Character from input is a valid character          
equal:
add $s0, $s0, -1
j isValid

#Character from input is not a valid character
notEqual:
add $s1, $s1, -1
j checkNum

#Check if the input is not duplicated
unique: 
la $t0, ($a0)
lb $t1, 0($t0) 
lb $t2, 1($t0) 
lb $t3, 2($t0) 
lb $t4, 3($t0) 

beq $t1, $t2, invalid
beq $t1, $t3, invalid
beq $t1, $t4, invalid       
beq $t2, $t3, invalid
beq $t2, $t4, invalid
beq $t3, $t4, invalid

jr $ra

invalid:
la $a0, invalidInput
li $v0, 4
syscall

j guess
```

Comment: I hope you didn't *just* start working on the semester project! Thursday isn't far away, and the MIPS is a harsh mistress...

Answer (score 1):

A few things here.

Firstly, you are using `.word 4` to store `input`. This allocates one word with value `4` which is probably not what you want. I changed this to `.space 256`.

Next, you use system call `8` to read read in a string with `5` characters. This will not work, as proper input is at least `6` characters, e.g.: `"1234\n\0"`.

So, anyway, your problem here is that when you return from your function `checkAll` you have forgotten to restore `$ra` and increment `$sp`. Below at the branches to invalid I changed `jr $ra` to:

```
lw   $ra, 8($sp)
addi $sp, $sp, 8
jr   $ra
```

This made the *happy* path of your execution perform without that particular error, but your program seems to suffer from some conceptual confusion. For example, you treat `checkAll` as a function by calling it with `jal` and returning with `jr`, yet in the invalid case of the function you `j` straight to `guess`. This uneven treatement is a waiting disaster and will likely lead to stack corruption.

Answer (score 0):

One problem is this:

```
checkAll:
addi $sp, $sp, -8     #This function alters the $sp for it's own calls
sw $ra, 8($sp)
sw $a0, 4($sp)
```

You reserve 8 bytes on the stack, but save `$ra` and `$a0` incorrectly. The code should be:

```
addi $sp, $sp, -8     #This function alters the $sp for it's own calls
sw $ra, 0($sp)
sw $a0, 4($sp)
```

The same thing before returning from the procedure `checkAll`.

```
lw $a0, 4($sp)      #But then it restores the $sp and is able to link back to the 'guess' call
lw $ra, 8($sp)
addi $sp, $sp, 8
jr $ra
```

Should be

```
lw $a0, 4($sp)
lw $ra, 0($sp)
addi $sp, $sp, 8
jr $ra
```